# Why does outlinePass cause the background to darken?

Tags: three.js

I built the scene with three.js
[image: scene]

I use outlinePass in the scene, an abnormal situation
[image: dark]

Why is this happening and how should I avoid it?

Comment: Um, maybe you've run into https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12678

Comment: @Mugen87   The version I am using is r96, and there is still a black background problem. I am not sure how to change it. Can you provide an example? I am in China now, I can't see the example you mentioned.Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's not an example but just a thread at github where the issue is tracked.

Comment: @Mugen87   I updated to r99, this version is no problem.